# Flutter Breaking News Ticker widget

Tags: flutter

Like with `News` websites to show important `BREAKING NEWS`, i'm trying to implementing a simple widget to show widget which stored into array one by one using delay, for example i have a `fadableWidgets` variable which that have 4 items, each items is:

```dart
Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: Text('${widget.posts[i].title}'),
        ),
      )
```

and i want to show every this item with one second delay with `Fade` effect, that means every one second we should one of `` item in the same position

## SAMPLE: [this link](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/cythilya/jquery-newsticker/blob/master/index.html) | or [this link](http://preview.codecanyon.net/item/breaking-news-ticker/full_screen_preview/8321816?ref=jqueryrain)

my code which that's not correct:

```
class LatestNews extends StatefulWidget {
  final List<Posts> posts;

  LatestNews({@required this.posts});

  @override
  _LatestNewsState createState() => _LatestNewsState();
}

class _LatestNewsState extends State<LatestNews> {
  int index = 0;

  List<Widget> fadableWidgets = [];

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    for (int i = 0; i < widget.posts.length; i++) {
      fadableWidgets.add(Expanded(
        child: Container(
          child: Text('${widget.posts[i].title}'),
        ),
      ));
    }
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: <Widget>[
        showWidget(),
      ],
    );
  }

  showWidget() {
    return Future.delayed(Duration(seconds: 1), () {
      return fadableWidgets[index];
      
      /*setState(() {
        index ++;
      });*/
    });
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be easily done with a [vertical marquee widget](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_vertical_marquee) or if you want to add any icons or rich text then you can use [any_widget_marquee](https://pub.dev/packages/any_widget_marquee)

Comment: this library is useful for texts not widgets, i want to show widgets like this library

Comment: any_widget_marquee can take any widgets.